# Is there a trick to getting spices to fix to raw almonds?

Tags: seasoning, almonds

I am trying to make a hot / spicy almonds using raw almonds and cayenne pepper.  Is there a simple non-messy way to get the cayenne pepper to stick to the almonds?

I imagine I could mix the almonds with olive oil before spreading it or similar but was hoping there is a better "hack" that is not as messy.

Comment: Very related, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22822/getting-flavor-powders-to-stick-to-nuts

Answer (score 4):

That's the trick to getting spices to adhere to nuts. If you are worried about the messiness perhaps your method can be improved. Put your nuts into a tossing bowl and slowly drizzle the oil over them. If tossing is a technique you are skilled with you can do that, but I'm guessing it's not, in which case you can stir with a spoon. It won't take much oil, maybe two tablespoons per pound. Maybe less. Then toss nuts again while sprinkling with cayenne. Or spread on a tray and sprinkle with cayenne there.

Lastly, if you are still struggling with the oily mess. Try enclosing in a sealable container and shaking. The oil will distribute and the mess will be contained.

Answer (score 1):

If you toss nuts in oil then roast them alone, the oil will get tacky as the lighter fractions come off in the heat or are absorbed by the nut.  That tacky oil will get the spices to adhere.

Comment: @bruglesco - I thought maybe that was just the starting point.

Comment: ohh maybe, I didn't read it that way but now that you mention it.